# Javascript, change CSS focused color for certain elements

Tags: javascript

I have a inline CSS like this one (part shown) for focused elements

```
    .InfoBox-body input[type=text]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=password]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=date]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=datetime]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=number]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=search]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=time]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=url]:focus,
    .InfoBox-body input[type=email]:focus,    
    .InfoBox-body select:focus{
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;    /* this is sort of blue */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
        border: 1px solid #88D5E9;
    }
```

Now I implemented some checks before send (loop form elements), and I use:

```
element.focus();
```

in a loop, when values don't match expected content.

This is working, by focusing trouble element but now I want more elaborate :) changing the focus color #88D5E9 into red.

I tried this approach

```
            element.style.cssText = `
                .InfoBox-body input[type=text]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=password]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=date]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=datetime]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=number]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=search]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=time]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=url]:focus,
.InfoBox-body input[type=email]:focus,    
.InfoBox-body select:focus{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
            `;
```

but isn't working.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using cssText... just use an invalid class and have the CSS Rule in your stylesheet.

Comment: can you be more specific please :)

Comment: `element.style.cssText` is not a place to put CSS selectors - it's a place to put CSS **rules** (the bit between the {})

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since nobody answered, here is my solution after a lot of digging. 
First of all, my CSS is embedded so change it means a lot of coding, looping through

```
document.styleSheets[]...
```

finding the right CSS, find the rule, etc.

I need this to focus a wrong input form and highlight with RED, so at submit I found this working:

```
    // element.style['-moz-box-shadow'] = "0 0 8px #FF0000";
        // element.style['-webkit-box-shadow'] = "0 0 8px #FF0000";
        // element.style['box-shadow'] = "0 0 8px #FF0000";
        // element.style['border'] = "1px solid #FF0000";

        element.style.cssText = `

            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FF0000;
            border: 1px solid #FF0000;

        `;
```

In fact, both are doing the same thing, **adding inline** CSS to that element.

```
<input id="uname" class="field-long" value="" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(255, 0, 0); border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);" type="text">
```

Seems more logic to edit the initial CSS rule from style but for the moment, this is simpler.

Now to revert when user clicks on focused element, I simply removed this inline and style from intial CSS will take over

```
        element.onclick = function () { 

            console.log('Click '+this.id);

            this.style.cssText = null;

        };
```

Maybe anyone needs this. Cheers!